# xld crashes with El Capitan

Tags: music, file-conversion

After upgrading to El Capitan (No complains apart of this one) [XLD](http://tmkk.undo.jp/xld/index_e.html) does not work anymore.

When I try to rip a CD, XLD crashes and I get the following trace back:

```
Process:               XLD [79196]
Path:                  /opt/homebrew-cask/*/XLD.app/Contents/MacOS/XLD
Identifier:            jp.tmkk.XLD
Version:               20141129a (148.2)
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           XLD [79196]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-10-04 14:49:21.854 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11 (15A284)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        9CCBACF6-B42B-0DCE-94E2-6BD9C09609E5

Sleep/Wake UUID:       5458CA8F-9C1F-4CAB-8190-184CF714214C

Time Awake Since Boot: 56000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       680 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        11

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x993309b9 __raiseError + 201
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x94324f11 objc_exception_throw + 276
2   CoreFoundation                      0x993308cd +[NSException raise:format:] + 141
3   Foundation                          0x90ce2fc5 +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:] + 96
4   XLD                                 0x0001c692 -[XLDController readPreGapOfDisc:] + 2354
5   Foundation                          0x90d15b37 -[NSThread main] + 45
6   Foundation                          0x90d158c2 __NSThread__start__ + 1550
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x9512b794 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x9512b70a _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x95128fa6 thread_start + 34

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9401c07a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9401b464 mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9922b096 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 214
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9922a4a1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1521
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x99229c46 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 390
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x99229aab CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x97919719 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 267
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9791951b ReceiveNextEventCommon + 503
8   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x97919314 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 99
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x9cd5b976 _DPSNextEvent + 1053
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x9cd5aef0 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1057
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x9cd5aac7 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 121
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x9cd4e23b -[NSApplication run] + 1063
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x9cd148c4 NSApplicationMain + 1630
14  jp.tmkk.XLD                     0x00002d12 _start + 216
15  jp.tmkk.XLD                     0x00002c39 start + 41
....
```

The crash occurs when it reads the gaps before ripping.

Any suggestion why this happens? I re-installed the newest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the XLD SourceForge page](http://sourceforge.net/p/xld/tickets/343/#d522)

> The crash report
>   indicates that XLD failed to get a vendor/product string from a drive,
>   or lost a connection itself. I guess the crash is caused by "Set
>   automatically if possible" option in "CD Rip" preference tab.

This solved the problem.